# Which int implementation to use?

Tags: c++, types, directx-12

I am programming a video game engine in c++, using the DirectX 12 API. By doing so I discovered the data type **__int64**, which is apparently a Microsoft specific sized type. Therefore two questions came into my mind:

Are sized int's (like "**int[size]_t**") generally more efficient than a standard **int**, assuming the right size is being chosen?

*AND*

which data type out of "**int[size]_t**", "**__int[size]**" and "**int[size]**" should I use, with efficiency and compatibility between different computer systems in mind?

Comment: On MS compilers `__int64` is exactly the same as `long long` and `std::int64_t`. It is just a name that existed before the latter were added to the standard.

Comment: I am sorry for posting a duplicate. Thank you though for the quick response <3

Comment: @BoPersson Rather, it is a name MS came up with since they didn't follow the previous C standard from 1999 until very recently.

Comment: MS Visual C++ started implementing what is now known as C++11 back in VS 2010 which included ``stdint.h`` and ``cstdint.h``. MS Visual C++ has explicitly stated that "C99" support is a non-goal, but since the final C++11 Standard says that C++11 must include the C99 Standard Library, those are part of VS 2013 and later library implementations. Similarly, MS Visual C++ does not yet support the C11 Standard Library but this is expected to be part of the C++17 Standard. It's still not the same thing as all the C99/C11 language features although the committee tries to keep C and C++ close.

Comment: Based on this question, I'm going to guess you may be new to C++ and/or DirectX. Please keep in mind that DirectX 12 is an expert graphics API that assumes you are already a master of using DirectX 11. If you are not, you should consider using DirectX 11 instead. See the [DirectX Tool Kit tutorials](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK12/wiki/Getting-Started).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I'd avoid any non-standard notation for integral types such as `__int64`, as you give up portability.

The *standard* fixed width types can be found in `<cstdint>`. But the compiler doesn't necessarily have to support them but if they do then they have to follow the specification to the letter: e.g. `std::int32_t` is a 32 bit 2's complement signed integral type. On your system, you'll probably find that `__int64` and `std::int64_t` are both `typedef`s for `long long`.

In terms of *performance* you might find you're better off with an `int`, as that's often the CPU's native integral type. (Although that's not always the case: Turbo C++ springs to mind as a notable exception). But, as you know, the specification of an `int` is intentionally vague. For example, it *could* be a signed magnitude type with range -32767 to +32767.

So it's a toss-up between portability and performance. You might find that `std::int_fast32_t` gives you the best of both worlds.

Reference http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer

Comment: Since you are specifically writing a DirectX 12 engine, you don't need to worry about 'weird' implementations of ``int32_t`` or ``uint32_t``. DirectX 12 is only supported on Windows platforms which all use 32-bit integers (x64 and ARM64 use LLP64 which only expands pointers to 64-bits, see [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384083.aspx))

Comment: In general, unless you are creating structures that must match on-disk binaries, network packets, cross ABI boundaries, or have 64-bit size requirements, on the Microsoft platform it's generally most efficient to just stick with ``int`` and ``unsigned int``. For C++ programming, you should also know when it is appropriate to use ``size_t`` and ``ptrdiff_t``.

Answer (score 0):

> Are sized int's (like "int[size]_t") generally more efficient than a standard int, assuming the right size is being chosen?

Depends on what you mean with efficiency. In terms of memory, you know how much space they take up, so they are generally more memory-efficient. There is also the `uint_leastn_t` types that can supposedly be used for memory optimizations (pick the smallest available type that can store at least *n* bits).

In terms of speed, aligned access might be a concern. The `int` type usually corresponds to the alignment of the CPU, so it might be faster than lets say `uint16_t`, but this is of course highly system-specific.

The C standard is fully aware of this issue though, so if speed is a concern you should use the `uint_fastn_t` types of cstdint.h, for example `uint_fast32_t`. Then you will get the fastest possible type with at least *n* bits.

---

> which data type out of "int[size]_t", "__int[size]" and "int[size]" should I use, with efficiency and compatibility between different computer systems in mind?

- For maximum portability you should use a fixed size type such as `uint32_t`.
- For maximum speed efficiency, you should use the "fast" types such as `uint_fast32_t`.
- For rare cases of memory efficiency optimizations, you can use the "least" types such as `uint_least32_t`.
- There is rarely ever any reason to use `int`. Mostly this is for backwards-compatibility with old code.
- There is no reason whatsoever to use non-standard `__int32`.

Language lawyers will post comments saying that stdint.h is no longer mandatory, but no sane person will use a new compiler that doesn't support it.